# Термин, который заменяет повторение слов, типа "После после послезавтра"

Tags: лексика, синонимы, терминология

Знаю, что таковой термин есть, но вспомнить не могу.

Comment: Вопрос в чем? название термина нужно? А я что-то не уверен, что он такой есть.

Answer (score 1):

Словарями фиксируется "послепослезавтра", с написанием в одно слово. В литературных произведениях встречается авторское "послепослепослезавтра" и даже "через послезавтра", но вряд ли в таких словах есть практический смысл: проще сказать "через четыре дня" или назвать день недели, и это будет понято без ошибок, вероятных при устной передаче.